# C# Array Different indexes

Tags: c#

Hi i want to search for character in a string array but i need to search Between 2 indices. For example between index 2 and 10. How can I do that?

```
foreach (var item in currentline[2 to 10])
{
    if (item == ',' || item == ';')
    {
        c++;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        data += item;
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is the normal for loop that allows you to set the start and end index positions

Comment: something like `for(int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)`.

Comment: and set `var item = currentline[i]` between the if else

Comment: what is "c" in your pseudo code?

Comment: @CodeNotFound No sorry, I was whrong. OP said "from index 2 to 10", so you were right :D

Comment: @xdtTransform you solution ruine the performance. Accessing through index is largely better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everey one finaly i fixed it by your guid thanks all

```
myarr = new mytable[50];
        number_of_records = 0;
        number_of_records = fulllines.Length;
        for (int line = 1; line < fulllines.Length; line++)
        {
            int c = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < record_lenth; i++)
            {
                string data = "";
                string currentline = fulllines[line];
                string value = "";
                for (int x = c; x < fulllines[line].Length; x++)
                {
                    value += currentline[x];
                }
                foreach (var item in value)
                {
                    if (item == ',' || item == ';')
                    {
                        c++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data += item;
                        c++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, `foreach` enumerates over a collection or any `IEnumerable`.

As the comments say, you can use a `for` loop instead, and pick out the elements you want.

Alternatively, since you want to search for a character in a string, you can use `IndexOf`, using the start index and count [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d93tkzah(v=vs.110).aspx) to find where a character is.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no use of the `c++` in your code I will assume that it's a vestige of code.

You can simply addess your issue like this:

- In the currentline
- Take char from index 2 to 10
- Till you find a char you don't want.
- concatenate the resulting char array to a string.

Resulting Code:

```
var data = "##";//01234567891 -- index for the string below.
var currentline= "kj[abcabc;z]Selected data will be between: '[]';";
var exceptChar = ",;";

data += new string( 
           input.Skip(3)
                .Take(8)
                .TakeWhile(x=> !exceptChar.Contains(x))
                .ToArray() 
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for characters in strings and get their indexes with this LINQ solution:

```
string str = "How; are, you; Good ,bye";
char[] charArr = { ',', ';' };
int startIndex = 2;
int endIndex = 10;
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1)
                        .Where(i=>charArr.Contains(str[i]))
                        .ToArray();
```

In this case we get `Enumerable.Range(2, 9)` which generates a sequence between 2 and 10 and the `Where` clause filters the indexes of the characters in `str` that are matching one of the characters inside `charArr`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a string method called [`string.IndexOfAny()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wh7x3fs(v=vs.110).aspx) which will allow you to pass an array of characters to search for, a start index and a count. For your example, you would use it like so:

```
string currentLine = ",;abcde;,abc";
int index = currentLine.IndexOfAny(new[] {',', ';'}, 2, 10-2);
Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Note that the last parameter is the count of characters to search starting at the specified index, so if you want to start at index 2 and finish at index 10, the count will be `finish-start`, i.e. `10-2`.